# trying to import this packages, but i keep getting this below error. see below

Tags: python, jupyter

i am trying to import this packages, but i keep getting this below error

`%logstophere`

`%logstart -rtq ~/.logs/ip.py append`

`%matplotlib inline`

`import matplotlib`

`import seaborn as sns`

`sns.set()`

`matplotlib.rcParams['figure.dpi'] = 144`

then i get this error message:
C:\Users\Olumide\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\IPython\core\magics\logging.py:130: UserWarning: Couldn't start log: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'C:\Users\Olumide/.logs/ip.py'
warn("Couldn't start log: %s" % sys.exc_info()[1])
Help please

Comment: What package(s) are you trying to import?

Answer (score 0):

1. 

It looks the error is in this line:

```
%logstart -rtq ~/.logs/ip.py append
```

It says that the file /.logs/ip.py does not exist.
Try to create it:

```
cd ~/.logs/
touch ip.py
```

2. 

There is no magic command %logstophere, I think you have to use %logstop instead

Comment: oh! it is a mistake, i meant %logstop, though i will try to create it now. thanks